# Filtering sensitive data with VCR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, vcr

I'm using VCR gem to record http interactions and replay them in future.  I want to filter-out my actual password value in the uri request.  Here's sample of what the uri looks like:

```
http://services.somesite.com/Services.asmx/Cabins
Username=long&Password=john&StartDate=03%2F22%2F2012&EndDate=03%2F29%2F2012
```

Though an explanation is provided here, I'm still not sure how to do it after a few attempts myself:

https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/v/2-0-0/docs/configuration/filter-sensitive-data

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: actually, i could just use regex to identify alphanumeric chars after Password= and before &

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.filter_sensitive_data("<SOMESITE_PASSWORD>") do
    ENV['SOMESITE_PASSWORD']
    # or $credentials['somesite']['password'] or whatever
  end
end
```

Essentially, you give VCR a bit of placeholder text, and then the block needs to return the real password, reading it from whatever the canonical password "repository" is.

Note that the real password is only needed the first time, when the request is recorded; on subsequent runs, it can be a fake password (as long as it's the same fake password used by the code making the request).

Answer (score 11):

for rails 4+, if you are using secrets.yml you might want to do

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  Rails.application.secrets.each do |k,v|
    config.filter_sensitive_data("ENV[#{k}]") { v }
  end
end
```

now you're sure not to forget any

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Rails 6+ with encrypted secrets, based on @montrealmike's answer:

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  Rails.application.credentials.config.each do |k, v|
    config.filter_sensitive_data("ENV[#{k}]") { v }
  end
end
```

The only change was replacing `Rails.application.secrets` for `Rails.application.credentials.config`.